# Why won't Capybara fill in my text field?

Tags: ruby, forms, capybara

When I grab a text field, fill_in isn't working. It says it can't find the field, even though it appears to know it's a field and appears to know its value? What am I doing wrong here?

```
f = page.all('input[type=text]').first
f
=> #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="input" path="/html/body/form/ol/li[1]/input">
f.value
=> "parsley"
fill_in f, with: 'paprika'
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="input" path="/html/body/form/ol/li[1]/input">
from /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/capybara-3.12.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:301:in `block in synced_resolve'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the answer by @bott correctly states `fill_in` takes a locator, which is the name, id, or associated label text of the input you want to fill in, not an element or CSS selector. Additionally since Capybara 3.7.0 you can call `fill_in` on a fillable element and skip passing the locator (as mentioned in the docs - "if no locator is provided will operate on self or a descendant") - in your case that would be

```
f.fill_in with: 'paprika'
```

On a side note there is no need to call `all(...).first` since there is a `first` method if all you want is the first matching element, however in general usage you really want to prefer methods that return single unique elements (find, etc), using scoping if necessary to ensure uniqueness, instead of `all` and `first`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and thanks for the best practice tip!

Answer (score 0):

fill_in use a locator, not an element, you are using "f" wich is an element. Doc reference
https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#fill_in-instance_method

> fill_in([locator], with: , **options)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the `f`variable anymore after `fill_in` I don't see a point in assigning a variable.

Have a look at `fill_in`: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#fill_in-instance_method

it expects a string, I am not sure if you can use a `CSS` selector.

You can alternativly also use `find` and `set`:

```
find('#my_container_id #id_of_first_input').set 'capybara'
find('#my_container_id #id_of_datetime_input').set I18n.l(Time.now, format: '%d-%m-%Y, %H:%M')
```

`find('input[type=text]').set 'foo'`should work as well, since `find` accepts any valid `CSS`, see: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#find-instance_method

Bonus, in case you'll need it: if you have a dropdown you can do: `find('#my_container_id #my_dropdown_id').find("option[value='#{factory2.id}']").select_option`